# Angular ssr takes too long for initial load

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-ssr

I have created a Angular ssr website that work so well, but its takes too much time for initial load, while I check in Chrome Performance tool it show its in idle state for first ~10 seconds.

[image]

Don't know what is wrong here.

Also when it take more CPU usage while executing.